# On refreshing jsp page got submited again

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I have created simple jsp servlet project on that when i submitting jsp form it insert data to specified table but after that when i refersh same jsp form get submitted and same data inserted to table..

**ItemUnit.jsp**

```
<form method="POST" action='ItemUnitHandler' name="frmAddUser">
    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="insert" />
    <table style="width:95%;margin-top:70px;" align="center">
        <tr>
            <td style="width:10%">&nbsp;</td>
            <td style="width:30%" align="right">Item Unit :</td>
            <td style="width:2%">&nbsp;</td>
            <td style="width:40%" align="left"><input type="text" name="itemUnitName" style="width:200px;" /></td>
            <td style="width:18%">&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr><td colspan="5">&nbsp;</td></tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="5" align="center">
                <input type="submit" class="button-2" value="Insert"></input> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                <input type="reset" class="button-2" value="Reset"></input>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

**Servlet post method code..**

```
String action = request.getParameter("action");
System.out.println("action :action action : "+action);
if(action == null)
{
    redirect = "ItemUnit.jsp";
}
else if(action.equalsIgnoreCase("insert"))
{
    ItemUnit objItemUnit = new ItemUnit();
//     System.out.println("request.getParameter : "+request.getParameter("itemUnitName"));
    objItemUnit.setItemUnit(request.getParameter("itemUnitName"));
    dao.addItemUnit(objItemUnit);  
    redirect = "ItemUnit.jsp";
}
```

please help me out from this problem...

Comment: Of course it will..And why do uwant to refresh.Do u want to disable refresh?

Comment: when you press  submit button then it will call the servlet and inserts.After that is it going to any other page?

Comment: `@Abhinav Kumar ` somethig like that...

Comment: `@JqueryLearner` i am redirecting to same page...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ideally, you should **land on a static result page**, instead of displaying the input form again. The idea is to force the browser to switch to a new URL so that a refresh will not re-trigger another data update. This is the simplest fix.

But if you prefer to use the same screen, you should **use a hidden token**. You must record some state since you want to differentiate 2 requests from one another: first and second request (the refresh).

Within your logic, plant a token the first time you display the input form. On any incoming request from the same session, check if you have used the token already and use it to determine if this is a second-time request. The diagram below will illustrate it further.

**Setup**

[image]

**Processing**

[image]

Comment: `@Jops`  how to determine that this is a second-time request..?

Comment: @win It's for the second approach. See the diagram. The token is the key.

Comment: If that's the case, you can prevent resubmission using option 1.